# Surpressing shell expansion when truncating variable obtained by asterisk

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion

In my folder I have following files:

```
roi_1_Precentral_L/
roi_1_Precentral_L_both.fig
roi_1_Precentral_L_left.fig
roi_1_Precentral_L_right.fig
roi_1_Precentral_L_slice.fig
roi_2_Precentral_R/
roi_2_Precentral_R_both.fig
...
roi_116_Vermis_10/
roi_116_Vermis_10_both.fig
roi_116_Vermis_10_left.fig
roi_116_Vermis_10_right.fig
roi_116_Vermis_10_slice.fig
```

I use following script to obtain a desired prefix of the filename for each of all 116 types:

```
for iroi in `seq 1 116`;
do
    d=roi_${iroi}_*/
    d2=${d:0:-1}         # <-- THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
    echo $d2
done;
```

**Desired output for iroi=1**:

```
$ roi_1_Precentral_L
```

**Actual output**:

```
$ roi_1_Precentral_L roi_1_Precentral_L_both.fig roi_1_Precentral_L_left.fig roi_1_Precentral_L_right.fig roi_1_Precentral_L_slice.fig
```

How can I avoid shell expansion in the emphasized line of code to make desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign to an array, the glob will be expanded on the first line, not later as of the `echo` as was the case with your original code.

```
d=( "roi_${iroi}_"*/ )
d2=${d:0:-1}            # Note that this only works with new bash. ${d%/} would be better.
echo "$d2"
```

If you expect multiple directories, `"${d[@]%/}"` will expand to the full list, with the trailing `/` removed from each:

```
d=( "roi_${iroi}_"*/ )
printf '%s\n' "${d[@]%/}"
```

---

With respect to avoiding unwanted expansions -- note that in the above, *every* expansion except for those on the right-hand side of a simple (string, not array) assignment is in double quotes. (Regular assignments implicitly inhibit string-splitting and glob expansion -- though it doesn't hurt to have quotes even then! This inhibition is why `${d:0:-1}` was removing the `/` from the glob expression itself, not from its results).

Comment: If there are multiple directories found, `d2` will contain only the *first* one.

Comment: Isn't that what the OP wants -- to find *exactly one* directory?

Comment: I find it hard to tell. There are no multiples for the given input.

Comment: ...well, there's a neat solution to both issues; extended appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to Question

If you wanted, you could quote to avoid expansion of `*` in `$d` ...

```
d=roi_${iroi}_*/
d2="${d:0:-1}"
echo $d2
```

... but then you could directly write ...

```
d2="roi_${iroi}_*"
echo $d2
```

... and the output would still be the same as in your question.

## Answer to Expected Output

You could do the expansion in an array and select the first array entry, then remove the `/` from that entry.

```
for iroi in {1..116}; do
    d=(roi_"$iroi"_*/)
    d2="${d[0]:0:-1}"
    echo "$d2"
done
```

This matches only directories and prints the first directory without the trailing `/`.

Comment: "*The `*` is already expanded in the line `d=roi_${iroi}_*/`.*" -- this is completely, utterly false. The `*` is assigned as a literal, since the right-hand side of string assignments has string-splitting and glob expansion suppressed. Run `d=/*; declare -p d` and you'll see `declare -- d="/*"` as output; no expansion took place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right. Thanks for the hint. It's always nice to (re)learn something when giving answers.